# Combine lookup with arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, lookup, array-formulas

Edit: This Spreadsheet explains the situation: [Lookup and Arrayformula](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQdHvWOb19evsJeeyCzc52_aPPt47LfEqe81YyNYRV0/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a select list in my configuration Sheet (B1). Here a user can select Data Set 1 or 2.

Now in column `E` I want to display the Values for each URL accordant to the config.

`={"Value from chosen Dataset";
ARRAYFORMULA(
LOOKUP(B2,{"Data Set 1","Data Set 2"},
{IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2:$D1000,G1:H1000,2,FALSE),""),
IFERROR(VLOOKUP($D2:$D1000,J1:K1000,2,FALSE),"")}))}`

As you can see there is an error which says my usage of LOOKUP is somewhat faulty. I feel like I run into issues because I want to LOOKUP one single field but then perform an ARRAYFORMULA based on that single cell.

Any ideas to resolve this? Feel free to edit the spreadsheet.

Comment: Because in F1–1000 there is a list of URLs and i want to execute formula 1, 2 or 3 in accordant to configuration!A1 Thanks for your response and question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have updated my post and created a sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula in `'MAIN FILE'!B1`:

`=ArrayFormula( { "Value from chosen Dataset";
IFERROR( CHOOSE(
LOOKUP( Config!B1, { "Data Set 1", 1; "Data Set 2", 2 } ),
VLOOKUP( $A2:$A20, 'Dataset 1'!A1:B15, 2, FALSE ),
VLOOKUP( $A2:$A20, 'Dataset 2'!A1:B15, 2, FALSE ) ), "" ) } )`

[image]